# Why two identical images forces two different color shade?

Tags: adobe-photoshop, cmyk, color-spaces

So, i have two images CMYK/8 bit to one image I set color #00ade3 to a shape, I then do the same to the other image (also same shape, just bigger) and it forces my color to #04ace3 instead, no way to set the color that I want.

To note that the color I'm trying to set does not receive any warning (gamma) I also noticed that if I set it using C(99) and Y(5) it works and receive the color.

So its not a real problem, I'm just wondering why two identical images behaves differently, maybe there is some setting I don't know?

**edit**: using [Adobe Kuler](https://color.adobe.com/it/create/color-wheel/?base=2&rule=Complementary&selected=2&name=Il%20mio%20tema%20Color&mode=cmyk&rgbvalues=0,0.44979701131549504,0.5901960784313725,0.08901960784313732,0.6996078431371946,0.8901960784313725,0,0.6784313725490196,0.8901960784313725,0.5901960784313725,0.295849145336294,0,0.8901960784313725,0.44735814491956544,0.0022601689551294177&swatchOrder=0,1,2,3,4) I noticed something weird: I enter my color #00ADE3 and it gives a CMYK (100,24,0,11) which is a lot darker.

Comment: Your'e mixing CMYK with RGB. *Hex numbers are an RGB value*. what at the CMYk values? And How are you determining the color? Eyedroppers? If so, what's the sample radius for the eye dropper?

Comment: It also sounds like you are confusing 'gamma' with 'gamut'.

Comment: @Metis,@Westside I open the shape -shape- symbol in its layer with double click and set the color, I confirm and re-open and the value changed, If I set C and Y values then change the RGB color the color is preserved. Yes I confused gamut with gamma! :)

Comment: Not sure what you aren't understanding where HEX is concerned. Using HEX values will almost *never* give you accurate CMYK values. as I've posted... HEX is RGB.

Answer (score 1):

After above comments...

By using Hex values to set a color in a CMYK file, you are asking Photoshop to convert that **RGB** color to a CMYK color. So there can be a shift based upon color profiles.

If you input C and Y values, you aren't asking for any *conversion*, you are adjusting values directly.

That is why you are seeing a difference.

If you're working on CMYK files and color is critical, don't rely on RGB values for colors.

Comment: why when I enter RGB it doesnt update the corresponding CMYK values in the color selection tool? **edit**: color profile is the same in both images.

Comment: Because the color picker is part of the **operating system** not Photoshop. While Adobe has integrated it a great deal in Photoshop (not so much in other apps), it still doesn't even see the image color profile until you close the picker -- and Photoshop reads the values and applies them.