# Color conversion, RGB to CMYK, different values in Photoshop

Tags: adobe-photoshop, cmyk, color-conversion, color-profile

I'm trying to enter the color **#00ADE3**, using [Adobe Kuler](https://color.adobe.com) and [ColorHexa](http://www.colorhexa.com/00ade3) and [another website](https://www.sessions.edu/color-calculator-results/?colors=00ade3,e34800); when I enter my color **#00ADE3** I get the same CMYK(100,24,0,11).

My Photoshop gives different CMYK values instead, here are my color profiles:

[image: my color profiles]

Any of you entering the **#00ADE3** gets the same CMYK? What color profile are you using?

Comment: How you get CMYK from Kuler? Site and photoshop build-in Kuler use ony Hex and RGB.
Also, why you want to transpose HEX into CMYK?

Comment: @SZCZERZOKŁY on the Kuler website if you type in a box the hex **00ADE3** it gives CMYK values in the box above.

Comment: It could be related to the fact that depending on your browser, the color #00ADE3 is displayed different than what you are able to see in Photoshop, specially when you are using the default color profile. Have you tried to use the proof preview choosing CMYK to see if the web browser look close to what you see in Photoshop? In general, there are some differences between photo viewers, editors and net browsers when it comes to color profiles, that's why first of all it will be great to calibrate your monitor using a hardware device / software calibration solution.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [AI Color Picker Panel and Pantone Color Finder shows different color values (CMYK, HEX and RGB) for a Pantone Colour](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/92131/ai-color-picker-panel-and-pantone-color-finder-shows-different-color-values-cmy)

Comment: You can try to reproduce that cmyk color in photoshop, export properly into a jpeg and to view the picture in the web browser. If the result is the same with what you see in Kuler (online), for sure is all about Photoshop Color management.

Comment: @user124853 is it possible it has to do with the color settings?

Comment: Indeed, this is what I am trying to say. Could be related to the way Photoshop handle the color profile, which result in displaying different perceptual color compared to what you are able to see into the web browser. Anyway, the subject is quite vast ...

Comment: Possible Duplicate: https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/92259/why-two-identical-images-forces-two-different-color-shade

Comment: @user124853 I don't know what else to try, every "color picker" app gives the CMYK, so the issue is my PC/settings. If you enter the **#00ADE3** in your software, what CMYK you get? What color profile are you using to get this result?

Comment: I'll make an experiment, could you be so kind and tell me what Document type do you intend to choose in Open/New dialog box Photoshop please? Thanks,

Comment: @user124853 I'm working on a PSD file in CMYK/8bit with 300dpi resolution, I noticed that different color profile yeld different CMYK values for **#00ADE3** but none near to what Kuler or any other program (I also tried android app!) will translate it..

Comment: OK, please find [these screenshots](http://imgur.com/a/KaU6w). I've made a PSD, CMYK 8bit, #00ADE3 (RGB 0,173,227) in CC 2015.5 and it looks and have the same values in Photoshop and Chrome browser Version 58.0.3029.110 (64-bit) as we can see, with or without any Color profile Embeded.  If you test this preview file in different browsers, there could be a color shift due to the color profile browser management. make sense?

Comment: On the other hand, there could be some variations depending on how you test the final output file and where (in browser or in Photoshop or in photo viewer that maybe doesn't support color management?); If you have an uncalibrated monitor also there could be some color variations.

Comment: LE: I've tested [Kuler](http://imgur.com/a/EfQpH) too and the result is the same measured with chrome eyedropper.

Comment: @user124853 does photoshop preserve the color once confirmed? To me if I confirm this color and re-open the color picker its different. Good thing that your CMYK are more similar to mine, respect Kuler which gives totally different values.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/59510/discussion-between-user124853-and-ritardi-net).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're really just asking why every site uses a different RGB to CMYK converter... there's no answer to that. They are all coded differently and use their own algorithms.

As I've posted.. if you need CMYK, stop using HEX and RGB to determine CMYK color.

It's like asking..... how come every time I buy apples at the store they are different?

Because different stores carry different breeds. If you want HoneyCrisp apples, you buy HoneyCrisp apples. You don't buy Fuji apples, which look remarkably similar, expecting them to taste just like HoneyCrisp apples. Just as you don't specify RGB (HEX) colors expecting them to always look like CMYK colors.

---

Anecdotal....

I recently was working on a project for a company and the company sent me their brand guidelines PDF. The guidelines contains color breakouts based on HEX values. It provided the Hex # then the RGB breakout then a Pantone equivalent.

One color was #fefe22:

[image]

Because **HEX is RGB**, the RGB breakout of 254,254,34 was correct. Same color.

But the Pantone specified 388:

[image]

Not even close.

So I asked how on Earth could someone, with the wherewithal to create brand guideline, specify such a horrible Pantone color?

The answer.. they used software rather than *actually looking at a Pantone color guide*. Because, if you set the color picker to fefe22, then click the <kbd>Color Libraries</kbd> button, there's a good chance the picker tell you.. Pantone 380-395 depending upon which Pantone book you use. All relatively more green or orange than the actual yellow. All because the picker is *guessing* at the closest possible value in the different color model.

---

It's *all too easy* to think software is infallible and always correct. That's just *not* true, especially where aesthetic matters like color is concerned. Software just uses a direct math conversion... and theres *no telling* what that actual math may be under the hood. It may be accurate 90% of the time. But it's rare that it is 100% accurate in all instances.

The crux of this is.. if you need an **accurate** CMYK color, you need to look at a color guide, not use some digital conversion method based on RGB colors.

Or, if you are adamant about using RGB to pick your CMYK colors, **always** use the **same** conversion tool. So the same math is used for all conversions.

Comment: the point is that different color picker (i tried 4 now) result to the same CMYK but my photoshop, did you try **#00ADE3** in your software? What CMYK did it give? What color profile were you using?

Comment: What CMYK values are you expecting? You've entered the world of color conversion and to be honest, there are *mountains* of books to explain what you are seeing. I've tried to explain a bit, but there's just no way enough detail could be provided on a site such as this to fully explain gamuts, conversions, profiles, etc. and how they all alter color perceptions. There's no "quick" answer for you here...

Comment: various color picker gives (100,24,0,11) I tested 4 different now, included one on android.

Comment: I read that in the question... what does Photoshop tell you?

Comment: my photoshop switches my #00ADE3 once confirmed, so I dont know its real CMYK, when I open the shape color picker, and enter and confirm this color, I re-open the shape color picker and it is different: #01ace3 (72,12,1,0)

Comment: ...and I get 72/21/1/0 as well. And if inputting HEX it is *only after clicking OKAY in the picker and reopening* that the color will be correct for CMYK. So Photoshop can convert the HEX to your CMYK profile. I would honestly **never** trust any online converter, I don't care who the company is. I can't stress enough that if you are concerned about CMYK **stop** looking at HEX values. You're detailing a **double conversion** here... HEX to CMYK, then CMYK back to HEX. That will **always** result in a different HEX value than you started with.

Comment: I meant 72/12/1/0 I mistakenly transposed the M value... it's 12.

Comment: @Ritardi.Net the other pickers most likely arent aware of the color profile info. That makes a HUGE difference. If you ever have calibrated your monitor to say sRGB or Adobe RGB you will notice that your image looks qute different before and after. But the programs tat do not have profile info are not aware of the difference. Also if your monitor has never been calibrated by you on the spot in the local conditions, with a physical colorimeter.  Then you also are not seeing the color you are going to print. The results can be WILDLY off.

Comment: @Ritardi.Net Also note that in addition to profile there is a something called a conversion intent to specify 4 ways to do the conversion, and in fact the conversion can be done in many many more ways. Because its a many to many conversion.

Comment: The amount of ignorance about colors by people who are supposedly working in the design field absolutely astounds me. I'd fire any so-called graphics designer that included software generated RGB and  CMYK conversion values in a branding guide.